# Alert show up when i refresh page

Tags: php

when I try to send msg, it's completely fine but when I refresh the page the alert show up

```
<?php 
    if(isset($error_message) >0){
    $message = "Grazie per averci contattato. Ci metteremo in contatto con voi molto presto.";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Remove `>0` and try again.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly when you want to show this message after Insert ?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to do this `if(isset($error_message) && $error_message > 0) {`?

Comment: #siddharth Ramani I want the message shows up after client click on submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Should have to try this...

```
<?php 
    if(isset($error_message)){
    $message = "Grazie per averci contattato. Ci metteremo in contatto con voi molto presto.";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unset the message once it's been set with:
`unset($error_message);`

Answer (score 0):

Try putting at the end of the code:

```
$error_message = 0;
```

So before you finish running the code, reset the variable